# Smooth Shapes in libgdx using ShapeRenderer

Tags: libgdx, rendering

I am using [ShapeRenderer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html) in libgdx to draw my only character to get rid of texture in my game.
But I am not getting quality results. Circle edges are distorted. I tried with high resolution and also by reducing size of character but result was same.

I go through [This answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/77950/how-to-render-rounded-shape-perfectly) , it is not applicable on ShapeRenderer.

Is there anyway I can apply any filter or anti-aliasing to make it look good?

[image: output 280X400]

Is it worth to draw using ShapeRenderer to get rid of a high resolution texture? 
I am able to induce 3d like effect by drawing lots of rectangle, circle, lines, curves etc. would it optimize the speed and fps of my game?

**Code:**

```
package com.test.com;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;

public class shapeRenderer implements ApplicationListener {

public OrthographicCamera camera;
int w,h;

ShapeRenderer sr;
    @Override
public void create() {
//Device width and height
w=Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
h=Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false, w, h);     // it is same as camera .setToOrtho(false);
camera.update();
sr= new ShapeRenderer();
Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
}    
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub    
}   
@Override
public void render() {
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(107/255f, 107/255f,107/255f, 1);
//Gdx.gl.glClearColor(190/255f, 190/255f,190/255f, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
camera.update();

        float x1=w/3;
        float y1=h/3;
        float cc=w/2;
        sr.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        sr.setColor(290/255f, 190/255f,190/255f, 1);
        sr.rect(x1,y1, cc,cc); 
        sr.setColor(107/255f, 107/255f,207/255f, 1);        
        cc=cc/2;
        sr.triangle(x1, y1, x1+cc, y1, x1, y1+cc);
        sr.setColor(290/255f, 290/255f,290/255f, 1);
        sr.circle(x1+cc,y1+cc, (cc*(2^1/2))/2);
        sr.end();
}              
@Override
public void pause() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub    
}   
@Override
public void resume() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub    
}    
@Override
public void dispose() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub    
}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could try turning on multi-sampling when applying the application configuration.
The [Multi Sampling Anti Aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisample_anti-aliasing) is controlled with the `numSamples` property for `AndroidApplicationConfigration` and with the `samples` property on the `LwjglApplicationConfigurtion`. 
So if you want to turn on anti aliasing for the desktop version you'd do something like;

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
  final LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
  cfg.samples = 4; 
  new LwjglApplication(new YourGameClass(), cfg);
}
```

A higher value for `samples` will mean a higher degree of anti-aliasing, but also a lower performance. Also, if it's not supported it will just fall back to the normal behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for pushing me into right direction. cfg.samples 2, 3 and 4 values are making significant changes. I think 4 is the max value for this property in libgdx for desktop. I will try it on high resol mobile display also. Do you have anything else in your quiever? :D

Comment: I haven't got anything else that I know will work, but depending on your scenario you could possibly try rendering the shapes aliased and then use a shader to blur or even apply anti-aliasing.

Comment: Thanks..Mentioning few links which were helpful. http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5997&p=28487 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186375/anti-aliasing-filled-shapes-in-libgdx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24345754/shaperenderer-produces-pixelated-shapes-using-libgdx